# store relative path on a web server to const variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I store relative path on a webserver into const variable
I tried this

```
private const string _ConfigurationFilePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/");
```

but obviously I cannot.

So how can I store relative path on a web server to const variable?

Comment: what do you mean by relative path? Can you ask by example

Answer (score 1):

Store the actual path, and call `MapPath` when you need it. You should probably call it anytime you write a server path anyway.

Comment: I don't know the server path, can you provide example code?